# Linux unique process ID within current boot session

Tags: c++, linux, pid

I'm writing a program in C++ that keeps track of processes over a long period of time and want to collect some random stats such as how often a PID has been reused.

Does Linux have something like Windows 'Process Start Key' so that each process can actually be uniquely identified within the current boot session even with PID reuse?

Comment: There is `pidfd_open`. You can also just `opendir("/proc/<thepid>")` and I think it will be unique. Ie. https://lwn.net/Articles/784831/

Comment: Perfect, just what I was looking for.

Comment: The inode number of pidfds is unforgunately not unique; as a matter of fact it's the same for all pids. Inode numbers of `/proc/${PID}` don't collide, but not guaranteed to be unique across PID reuse. – The lack of true process UUIDs have been a long ongoing issue, and one of the few topics where I strongly agree with the systemd developers.

Comment: `C++ that keeps track of processes` Are these process your child processes?

Comment: No, i'm just monitoring all processes and keeping a table of everything that was run (pid, command etc) so needed something unique to identify each one.